# ALTER TABLE ADD field getting ORA-00942 error

Tags: sql, oracle

I run the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD date_terminated DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NULL;
Commit;
```

and I get the following error message:

> SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>
> *Cause:
>   *Action:

When I `select * from users`, I get records.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Just a note, you try to add a _column_, and you get _rows_ when you select.

Comment: try adding schema name as `alter table YOUR_SCHMEA.users`

Comment: Maybe `users` is a synonym?

Comment: As an aside, what do you expect from 'DEFAULT SYSDATE NULL'?  And there is no need to COMMIT DDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a permissions issue: I did not use the owner of the table to alter the table.  Switching to a connection with those credentials fixed the issue.